# A silly question about web3.eth.sign

Tags: web3js, metamask, signature, cpp-ethereum

I'm a beginner and I need to sign the data with metamask，Find the document https://learnblockchain.cn/docs/web3js-0.2x/web3.eth.html#sign

then In the browser's debug desk ，i try run

```
web3.eth.sign('0xB2b63803188fb6efafD83FE67bec878eD4d8940B','data',console.log)
```

metamask responded to my request，and popped up the prompt

But after I confirm it，No return value

If anyone knows, please help me，thanks

Comment: The documents refers to the old web3 v0.20. The last version is v1.3 uses another syntax  https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.0/web3-eth.html#sign.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i know

Signature information of `eth.sign` needs to be treated with `web3.sha3`

but `personal.sign` don't need it